# Как это состояние называется?

Tags: терминология

Простите, не могу придумать внятного заголовка для вопроса.

Нужно одним словом охарактеризовать состояние человека, который не в состоянии заставить себя заниматься какой-то конкретной деятельностью, даже любимой работой.

"Идиосинкразия" не предлагать. В подобном значении термин употреблен у Стругацких ("За миллиард лет до конца света"), но там это была *болезненная* реакция на попытку заняться такой деятельностью, а мне нужна именно психологическая составляющая: просто откладываю под разными предлогами то, чем хочется (и надо!) заняться именно сейчас.

Господа, здесь нет лени или нежелания работать. Человек может сутками заниматься тяжелой и нудной работой, но когда ему надо отвлечься и переключиться на что-то приятное - и для того есть возможность - он не в состоянии этого сделать.

> Прокрастинация

Прокрастинация это откладывание "на потом" **неприятных** дел. А тут совсем другое, нужным и **интересным** для него делом заняться не может.. 
Вот знаете как ребенок вдруг отказывается есть любимую кашу. Может, чем-то другим увлекся, может просто сыт, может немного нездоров или сидеть неудобно... Или просто объелся этой кашей и перерос её и хочет селедки с луком. Другая мамаша с ума сходит, "за маму, за папу, за бабушку", считает что дитя капризничает.
А теперь представьте, что капризничает взрослый - и не с едой, а с делами. И не для мамы, а для себя... 
Ну вроде как нужно термин вложить в уста психиатра, общающегося с неспециалистом. Т.е. термин должен быть не просторечным, но не обязательно профессиональным...
Как-то так:
~ Начиналось всё с простой [КакТамЕёНазвалии] на фоне переутомления и постоянного стресса, потом уже стали наблюдаться опасные отклонения...

//========================================

Делаю последнюю одну попытку объяснить на аналогии.
Вот ортодоксальные евреи по субботам избегают какой-то определенной деятельности. 
Теперь представьте, что у человека (совсем не еврея и совсем не по религиозным мотивам) такой шаббат наступает без всякой связи с днем недели и в отношении совершенно произвольной деятельности.

Вот к примеру, допустим, мне сейчас надо сделать какое-то важное, срочное и даже приятное дело, а то и не одно, а я сутками сижу на форуме и решаю совсем не срочный и не жизненно важный вопрос с названием этого состояния. Назавтра все может быть наоборот, вот не захочется мне на форум заходить - и все тут. Буду заниматься чем угодно, хоть в потолок сутками плевать...

Вот человека, у которого подобное поведение становится постоянной и единственной нормой существования, реально доводящей до ручки и его, и окружающих, мне нужно охарактеризовать, желательно (но не обязательно) медицинским или психиатрическим термином.

Ну какая же это апатия, если человек может сразу десятью делами заниматься (или вообще ничем не заниматься), но только не тем, чем надо и чем хочет? Более того, он может даже рваться именно к той детеяльности, но вот по непонятным причинам...

//---------------------

Ближе всего (но, увы, не полностью) соответствует моим чаяньям "бессознательно избегание". На нем пока и остановлюсь.
Спасибо за обсуждение, [[@mueller](/users/1377/mueller)](/users/1377/mueller) - вам особо.
Но если вдруг кто сообразит что-то "получшее" - буду весьма признателен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм, не знаю, подойдёт ли для Вашего текста, но описываете Вы совершенно точно то, что психологи зовут бессознательным избеганием. Когда точно **надо** и вроде бы вполне **хочу**, но почему-то всё то отодвигаю, то оттягиваю, то не с руки как-то... 
Если правильно Вас понял, это наудачу можно выразить разве просторечно - самого себя динамлю...

- Поподробнее - так называют состояние, когда я в нормальном, "громком" дневном сознании уверен, что прямо сейчас желаю делать нечто - да потому что всегда этого желаю, и недоволен, когда этому что-то мешает. А прямо сейчас - самое время, да и необходимость кстати подвернулась...
- В то же время на уровне "тихого", "сумеречного" сознания, как говорят нормальные люди (не психологи) - на донышке души - я категорически не желаю (не важно почему) заниматься именно этим именно сейчас. И сам с собой играю в прятки - "сумеречное" Я подкидывает поводы не делать, а "дневное" как бы нехотя соглашается...
- Все для того, чтобы "дневное" не вошло в конфликт с собственными убеждениями и само для себя выглядело прилично, говорят психологи.

Comment: ну-ка ну-ка... Это горячо.
Чуть поподробнее можете? Про бессознательное избегание.  

Для текста все подойтет. Мой текст - что хочу, то и напишу. Лишь юы суть отражало.

Comment: >Поподробнее - так называют состояние,  
  
Да, это действительно горячо... Я посмотрю что-нибудь по этой теме, потом определюсь окончательно, подходит ли мне.  
Спасибо.

Comment: Если "может сутками заниматься тяжелой и нудной работой и не может переключиться", то , может, это
 Ригидность-(от лат. rigidus – жесткий, твердый) — неготовность к изменениям программы действия в соответствии с новыми ситуационными требованиями.
ИЛИ: «Монотония – напряжение, вызванное однообразием выполняемых действий, невозможностью переключения внимания, повышенными требованиями"

Comment: Спасибо, эти термины мне кажутся более далекими от сути нежели предложенное. Но я их тоже посмотрю.

Comment: Если речь о переутомлении, то оно вызывает синдром хронической усталости– заторможенность, апатию, недееспособность.

Comment: Нет, Людмила, не о переутомлении. Это только одна из возможных причин, как я понимаю. Я же сказал, человек на первом этапе этого заболевания(?) продолжает оставаться активным, но по малопонятным причинам избегает какой-то конкретной деятельности. Через какое-то время к ней возвращается, но появляются новые "фобии"... То, что тут называлось - это совершенно другое. Бессознательные избегание - это горячо, но не более.

Мне не хотелось бы раскрывать тут все детали  и причины, побудившие меня задать этот вопрос, но мне нужен или правильный термин (пусть не медицинский, бытовой), или никакого.

Comment: Начинается обычно с простой апатии, заканчивается стрессом,депрессией

Answer (score 4):

"...просто откладываю под разными предлогами то, чем хочется (и надо!) заняться именно сейчас"

Это явление называется прокрастинацией! Встречала это слово много раз именно в таком смысле во многих статьях.

А вот цитата из Эдгара По, которая приведена в соотв. статье в Википедии:
Перед нами работа, требующая скорейшего выполнения. Мы знаем, что оттягивать её гибельно. Мы слышим трубный зов: то кличет нас к немедленной, энергической деятельности важнейшее, переломное событие всей нашей жизни. Мы пылаем, снедаемые нетерпением, мы жаждем приняться за труд — предвкушение его славного итога воспламеняет нам душу. Работа должна быть, будет сделана сегодня, и все же мы откладываем её на завтра; а почему? Ответа нет, кроме того, что мы испытываем желание поступить наперекор, сами не понимая почему. Наступает завтра, а с ним ещё более нетерпеливое желание исполнить свой долг, но по мере роста нетерпения приходит также безымянное, прямо-таки ужасающее — потому что непостижимое — желание медлить. Это желание усиливается, пока пролетают мгновения. Близок последний час. Мы содрогаемся от буйства борьбы, проходящей внутри нас, борьбы определенного с неопределенным, материи с тенью. Но если единоборство зашло так далеко, то побеждает тень, и мы напрасно боремся. Бьют часы, и это похоронный звон по нашему благополучию. В то же время это петушиный крик для призрака, овладевшего нами. Он исчезает — его нет — мы свободны. Теперь мы готовы трудиться. Увы, слишком поздно!

Как мне кажется, это подходит и к откладыванию приятных дел тоже. Что-то у меня не получается найти этот термин в толковых словарях, видимо он еще "не устоялся". То, что дело неприятно - одна из самых распространенных причин прокрастинации, но далеко не обязательное ее условие. В общем случае это замена важных дел (и любимых и нелюбимых), к которым "страшно" приступить из-за их объема, мелкими и незначительными действиями. Чтобы себя оправдать - вроде как и что-то делаю, не бездельничаю. А на самом деле выходит именно безделье. Так случается и с давно вынашиваемым человеком проектом, который он обдумывал долгое время и мечтал о его осуществлении. А когда все возможности есть, и надо взяться за дело - так тысячи мелких отговорок вырастают. Так я понимаю этот термин, исходя из того, что читала об этом явлении. Относится и к повседневным ситуациям: надо написать кому-то письмо (хоть любимой, но взять и написать), а человек читает новостные сайты и т.п.  Мне кажется, как раз то, что вам подходит. Или мне не удается понять состояние, которое вы описываете.

Comment: Нет, не пойдет. Ответил в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, добавленный в мой ответ абзац про приятность/неприятность дела. Почему-то не получилось его запостить как комментарий. Видимо, из-за числа символов.

Comment: В английском интернете про то, что дело неприятно - ни слова. Это, видимо, издержки русской википедии. Mueller выше описал то же самое явление, только не назвав его по имени.

Comment: да? Вообще-то я этот термин знал и без интернета... Тогда я посмотрю английские тексты, потом определюсь...
А вот насчет "то же самое" я как-то не понял... Вроде бы там совсем другая симптоматика. Хорошо, спасибо, я пока беру тайм-аут...

Да нет, ну что вы... Первый же абзац в Вики: 
 In accordance with Freud, the pleasure principle may be responsible for procrastination; humans **prefer avoiding negative emotions, and delaying a stressful task**.   
  
Это другое...

Comment: Это другое... Мне нужно "с точностью до наоборот". 
Ну вот физически здоровый человек способен часами смотреть нелюбимую передачу, только чтобы не нажимать кнопку на пульте. Сам объяснить не может. не хочу - и все. 
Причем назавтра это он делает без проблем... Зато что-то другое появляется подобного типа... Не сталкивались с таким? А я это описание из жизни беру, поэтому менять "диагноз" не хотелось бы.

Comment: Если еще интересно... Прочитала ваш вопрос с добавлениями, посмотрела комментарии и словари, английскую Википедию. Считаю, что насчет прокрастинации вы не правы. Определения: (Вики) procrastination refers to the act of replacing more urgent actions with tasks less urgent (Merriam Webster) to put off intentionally the doing of something that should be done (Princeton) putting off or delaying or defering an action to a later time и т.п. Везде одно и то же. Прокрастинация относится как к приятным, так и к неприятным делам - к любым. Муж этим "болеет", подробно изучали этот вопрос в свое время :-

Comment: По мне, так все, что вы написали - идеально под прокрастинацию подходит. Но "бессознательное избегание" - уж очень красивый термин! Сама теперь использовать буду! Спасибо за интересное обсуждение!

Answer (score 2):

Актуальный и злободневный вопрос.
Сам на горьком опыте знаком с этой проблемой (проблемой? явлением?).
Ознакомившись с представленными выше трактовками и доводами, акцентировал бы Ваше внимание на небольшой, однако принципиальной корректировке термина.

**Под**сознательное вписывается в Ваш конъюнктурный контекст несколько более претенциозно, чем дотоле упомянутое **бес**сознательное (не имею морального права исправлять, лишь предлагать на Ваш суд и выбор); могу лишь аргументировать это, ссылаясь на работы Фрейда, в которых *бессознательное* относилось к области психоанализа, раскрывающегося через аспект сновидений.

Безусловно, могу и ошибаться, буду рад аргументированным (в значении *объективным*) исправлениям.

Comment: спасибо, конечно, но этому вопросу уже год.
Актуальным его никак не назовешь.

Comment: Пардон, не обратил внимания на даты. 
Хотя для меня актуален и по сей день. :)

Answer (score 1):

Индифферентность не подойдёт? Или её синонимы: отрешенность, равнодушие, безучастность, отстраненность, безразличие, транс?

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то... У вас что-то вроде Обломова или даже Манилова, а тут скорее Полесов из 12 стульев. Может заниматься чем угодно, только не тем, чем надо, причем вполне осознавая, что именно ему надо заниматься, более того - внутренне даже хотеть заняться именно этим. 
Правда, у Полесова это была обычная безалаберность холерика, а мне надо описать случай более глубокий на почве внутренней самоорганизации. Чем-то он должен напоминать главного героя "За спичками", только тот был скорее сангвиник, а у этого должна энергия бить.

Answer (score 1):

В терминах, обычно как раз описываются болезные явления, и если при нежелании работать нет других симптомов (например подавленность и пр.), то, именно термин, существует вряд ли.

Если уйти от терминологии, то есть слово **нехоть** ("неохота, нежелание; недостаток готовности, ревности, усердия; отсутствие радушия, услужливости; лень, вялость, косность во всем", - В. И. Даль). А также жаргонные - **влом, ломает**.

Добавлено

Вроде подходит слово **шизоидность**. Вот, что я прочитал в одном из описаний шизоидного типа личности

> Вот шизоид начал работать по замыслу своего руководителя. И если вдруг возникло противоречие между альтернативными вариантами, он с интересом разрабатывает противоречивые идеи, ему любопытны побочные продукты его работы. «Побочные» продукты он не отбрасывает, даже если они противоречат его основной идее, ведь именно они могут оказаться более продуктивными в других отношениях. Он развивает их, копается в деталях, зарывается в мелочах - и забывает о цели. К результатам своего мышления он относится более или менее бесстрастно: вон, дескать, что получается...

Источник:http://treko.ru/show_dict_1303

Comment: Нет, не пойдет. Вполне себе "хоть" и никакой вялости. Наверное, я что-то не так спросил, коли вы вслед за Людмилой совешенно другое состояние предлагаете. И "влом" тоже то слово.

Comment: Шизоидность - это слишком общо. Это общий поведенчиский тип, она может прояляться совершенно по-разному. 
Да и не та симптоматика, я тут даже разбираюсь немного.

Блин, я понимаю, что  описываю не слишком распространённый случай, но не до такой же степени, чтобы никто не сталкивался... Самое обидное, что не могу найти хороший пример из литературы...

Ладно, проехали. Надо или отложить поиски или вообще идею откинуть.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуем объясниться так. М. А. Шолохов долго не мог закончить свой роман "Тихий Дон". По поводу этого романа и без того возникла страшная полемика. Автор не мог сделать Мелехова антисоветчиком: роман просто не был бы закончен в печати (не напечатан) по "идейным соображениям" литературного общества того времени. Он не мог вывести своего героя "почти советским" человеком, потому что  в соответствии с контекстом романа он не мог быть таковым в принципе - согласно своим тайным, внутренним убеждениям, понятным и самому читателю, и своему прямому, неконформистскому характеру, и такая трактовка образа противоречила бы целостности и правдивости авторского замысла (впрочем, об этом можно только догадываться). И вот эта затяжка окончания романа, кажется, подходит по своим параметрам к вопросу, поднятому [@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus). Автор ХОЧЕТ закончить роман, но в сложившихся обстоятельствах НЕ МОЖЕТ сделать так, как следовало бы согласно концепции целостности авторского замысла. Как найти золотую середину, чтобы и волки были сыты, и овцы целы? Автор набрасывал несколько окончаний, но все они, после анализа течением времени, его не устраивали. Дилемма казалась почти неразрешимой. Садиться за стол с каждым разом становилось всё труднее. В душе автора могло возникнуть то СОСТОЯНИЕ, которое мы сейчас обсуждаем. Имеется ЖЕЛАНИЕ, но почти НЕТ ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ его выполнить. Пожалуй, это состояние - ТВОРЧЕСКАЯ ДЕПРЕССИЯ (у автора. А у обычного человека - просто разновидность обыкновенной ДЕПРЕССИИ, которая не сопровождается потерей работоспособности)

Comment: Нет. Сейчас уже порядком подзабылось, что я хотел тогда выразить, но это явно не то, что Вы описали. "Депрессия" еще как-то соответствует (тоже очень и очень условно) но уж творчество там рядом не лежало.

Спасибо.