# Как называется "болезнь" или зависимость, когда не можешь делать только что-то одно?

Tags: терминология

Делаешь что-то, даже если это то, что тебе нравится, но понимаешь что очень скучно. Невозможно делать одно. Хоть музыку включить, хоть сериал какой, но только не ОДНО ЕДИНСТВЕННОЕ ДЕЛО.

Comment: Вряд ли есть специфический термин. Посмотрите для начала здесь. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19920. Если сочтете, что ваш вопрос принципиально отличается от обсуждаемого там, дам ответ более развернутый, хотя вряд ли иной по сути.

Answer (score 2):

1) Многие люди чувствуют себя комфортно, когда занимаются несколькими делами. **Психологи называют это явление многозадачностью** и считают, что оно причиняет вред и что нужно избавляться от такой зависимости.

Например, в исследовании ученых из Стэнфордского университета (США)говорится, что **мультитаскинг не только снижает эффективность, но также снижает IQ и повреждает мозг.** https://yogajournal.ru/blogs/glavnyy-redaktor-yj-ellen-ferbeek/kak-perestat-delat-sto-del-odnovremenno-i-stat-bolee-osoznannym

2)  **Но каковы же причины такого явления?** Как мне кажется, четкого ответа нет

Например: "Ученые из Университета Огайо выяснили, что люди, практикующие многозадачность, чувствуют себя лучше. Но лучше не от того, что успевают сделать больше (это не так), а от того, что делают больше. Автор исследования Жен Вонг утверждает, что ловушка кроется **в неправильной трактовке позитивных сигналов.** Люди чувствуют себя более удовлетворенными работой, но не становятся продуктивнее".  https://vc.ru/flood/6189-everything-is-nothing

3) Интересно то, что, как говорят ученые, **мозг одновременно может выполнять не более двух задач,** а третью он блокирует.

При выполнении только одной задачи у человека происходит активная работа обоих полушарий головного мозга. Когда добавлялась вторая задача, то **мозг разделял обязанности между двумя полушариями:** левое полушарие отвечало за одну задачу, а правое независимо решало другую. https://www.gazeta.ru/science/2010/04/16_a_3352769.shtml?updated

4) Как мне кажется, **человек стремится к равномерной нагрузке полушарий.** При решении сложных логических задач нужен эмоциональный фон (например, музыка). Но если задача требует работы обоих полушарий, то дополнительный эмоциональный фон отключается, человек его не слышит. Если же постоянно загружено только одно полушарие, **то появляется дискомфорт и усталость, и даже интересное занятие начинает казаться скучным.**

Кроме того, **многомерное информационное поле дает ощущение причастности к жизни**, люди  не чувствует себя одинокими.

5) Возможно, психологам виднее, но по своим собственным ощущениям я бы сказала, что **наш мозг способен к саморегуляции:** если требуется сосредоточенность в решении задачи, то человек или выключает  радио (телевизор), или перестает их воспринимать.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, подходящее слово для всех подобных явлений — **гиперактивность**. Психика человека находится в таком возбужденном состоянии, что он не может сосредоточиться на чем-то одном, его внимание "прыгает" с предмета на предмет. В своем слабом проявлении гиперактивность — это чувство скуки, а наличие двух-трех параллельных  раздражителей решает проблему и позволяет нормально функционировать.

А еще я думаю, что поток информации в современном мире столь интенсивен, что подобная повышенная активность нашей психики, быстрое переключение становятся просто необходимыми во многих ситуациях. Это как бы искусственная гиперактивность, которую мы у себя вызываем. Проблема в том, что долго находиться в таком состоянии вредно, но расслабиться мы зачастую не можем, потому и скучно нам без "фонового" телесериала. Это как "голод" по физической нагрузке, который возникает у спортсмена.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь ответ достаточно прост - расконцентрация.  Это не умение концентрировать внимание на конкретном действии,  предмете, явлении. Причины могут зависеть от различных факторов: воспитание, развитость, черты характера, темперамент, самочувствие и т. д.  Эта проблема вполне решаема.  Существует достаточно много техник по развитию концентрации.